# No synapse button in ESB 4.8.1 Management console

Tags: wso2, apache-synapse

I downloaded WSO2 ESB 4.8.1 and started the wso2 server and got the management console up and running. But there does not exist a button called "Synapse" under the configure tab in the top left corner in the management console. I want it to open the synapse-configuration.xml to change the configuration to secure the service. Can anyone tell me why this "Synapse" button is not there in the configure tab in the ESB management console and hoe I can get it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use "Source view" menu. It will open the synapse-configuration.xml. See following image.

[image]